# Probability of Ruin of Insurance Model with Exponential payoffs

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I'm having trouble proving a result I think should be true for the insurance payout model.
Say you have $U_n = x + c*n - X_n$
where $X_n = X_{n-1} + Y_n$ and the $Y_i$ are all iid $Y_i \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ and $X_0 = 0$
How do I show that if $c\le E[Y_i]=1$ then there is a 100% probability that there exists an $m$ such that $U_m<0$. I.e. The probability of ruin is 1.

My first thought was defining a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is the probability of ruin for the process given that the starting capital is $x$ (as in the definition for $U_n$).
First I can observe that $f(x)=1$ for all $x<0$. Then I can observe that the probability of ruin for $f(x)$ has a probability given by
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}f(x+1-u) du\\
f(x)&=\int_0^{x+1}e^{-u}f(x+1-u) du + \int_{x+1}^{\infty}e^{-u} du
\end{align}
where in the second step I used the fact that $f(x)=1$ for all $x<0$.
I then yield
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^{x+1}e^{-u}f(x+1-u) du + e^{-x-1}\\
f'(x)&=e^{-(x+1)}f(x+1-(x+1)) - e^{-(0)}f(x+1-(0)) - e^{-x-1}\\
f'(x)&=e^{-x-1}f(0) - f(x+1) - e^{-x-1}\\
f(x+1)&=e^{-x-1}f(0) - f'(x) - e^{-x-1}\\
f(x)&=e^{-x}f(0) - f'(x-1) - e^{-x}\\
f(x)&=e^{-x}(f(0)-1) - f'(x-1)
\end{align}
I can solve this final equation for $0<x<1$ by using the fact that $f'(x-1)=0$ for $0<x<1$
I can then solve this equation for $1<x<2$ by using the fact that I can find the derivative of the equation for $0<x<1$
I can keep doing this. But this gives me quite nonsensical results. What am I doing wrong and how else can I solve this problem?

Any pointers/help greatly appreciated

Comment: $U_n = n(\frac xn + c - \frac{\sum_i Y_i}n)$, then use the law of large numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would this work for the case that $c=1$, since the mean will stay at $x$?

Comment: It’s still true but more difficult. Then, $U_n / n^{.5}$ approaches mean 0, stdev 1, so for a given $U_n$ the probability is near $0.5$. One ugly way to do it is to keep “restarting” the process choosing to increase n by enough each time so that the probability is less than $.6$ , so that the probability of being positive always after after $m$ stages is less than $.6^m$ which approaches 0.

Comment: I would agree that $\frac{U_n}{n^{0.5}}$ approaches mean 0, stdev 1, but I'm unsure how I can argue that $U_n$ approaches mean x, stdev n from that. I'm not sure that I can just multiply through by $n^{0.5}$ after taking the Law of large numbers limit. Intuitively I understand your argument, but I'm just not sure how I can use the law of large numbers here. Thanks; a bit more help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of CLT. With law of large numbers, even if the standard deviation is large, that could still mean that the probability of ruin is zero (given that the mean is $x$), right?